# Como verificar JWT em cada requisição

Tags: php, web-service, api, rest, jwt

Estou fazendo um sistema de login em *php* e tentando autorizar com `JWT`. não estou utilizando nenhuma biblioteca, fiz uma classe chamada `Jwt` que eu passo os paramentos e gero o *Token* e também passo o *token* e me retorna um objeto com as informações do payload.

**Até agora a lógica da meu sistema ta assim:**

No meu código eu tenho uma rota */login* que manda os dados do formulário para */login/auth* e dentro do */auth* eu faço a consulta no `BD` e se der certo eu gero o *token*

**Minha dúvida é:**

Como verificar o *token* em cada requisição?
Posso salvar o *token* em um `cookie`?
Em cada verificação vou ter q consultar o `BD` para verificar o *token*?

Se já fez em outra linguagem pode dizer, talvez me ajude na lógica.

Comment: Vou aguardar a resposta de alguem mais experiente, pois no meu sistema eu faço a verificação do token no BD

Comment: Essa foi a primeira vez que perguntei aqui, costuma demorar pra alguém responder?

Answer (score -1):

Uma API Rest não deve conter estado entre requisições, então salvar o `token` em um cookie para verificação não seria o ideal.

Não conheço bem a linguagem `php` porém eis uma proposta: crie um filtro ou um middleware para todas as requisições. Todas as requisições dos clientes enviam o token no cabeçalho `Authorization`, quando essa requisição entrar no filtro você recebe recupera as informações do payload e gera um novo token de validação, teste se os dois são equivalentes.

Vale ressaltar que esta técnica só funcionará em tokens simples, tokens mais complexos utilizam, por exemplo, um tempo de expiração e para este caso essa técnica não funcionaria. O interessante seria que utilizasse alguma biblioteca que implementasse esse recurso de forma mais completa.